# Selecting network interface in MAAS

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, openstack

I'm installing Ubuntu OpenStack: The Canonical Distribution and at one stage of installation it asks me:

> Please select a network interface that is not currently listening to any DHCP or DSN requests. This will be the interface MAAS will use to manage its own DSN/DHCP services

I have a server with two nic's , one (eth0) is connected to the network and the other (eth1) should be connected to a switch to control other servers.

**What is the command to select eth1?**

Answer (score 0):

Yep if eth1 is not listening on any existing DHCP/DNS servers then that will be the one you choose for MAAS to manage its own DNS/DHCP services.